# Notepad++ and embedded Perl - syntax highlighting inside specific tag

Tags: html, perl, syntax, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

In order to make `Notepad++` highlight embedded Perl templates as HTML I've added `.ep` file extension in style configurator. However, it is very common to have large chunks of pure Perl code in these `.ep` files, which are marked with `<% perl code %>` tags.

Are there any ways of making `Notepad++` interpret everything between `<%` and `%>` as Perl code and highlight it as Perl, while everything outside these tags should be considered HTML?

Comment: You know what guys... It actually highlihts _something_ between `<%` and `%>`, for instance - keyword `for`, but it is as far as I concern not perl'ish syntax, but, some, generic or something (it doens't highlight `foreach` for example). What we need to find out is where in `stylers.model.xml` and `langs.model.xml` this behavior is specified and than change it to perl'ish syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it's not possible with Notepad++ ? http://superuser.com/questions/235320/different-language-syntax-highlighting-within-same-file

Comment: That's probably true. Switched to Sublime Text 2 though it is not freeware.

Answer (score 1):

Templating Engines such as `Template Toolkit` have specific syntax that is used inside the delimiters `<% perl code %>` that is then converted to and executed as Perl during the template execution (just before rendering) so even if you *could* have `perlish` syntax highlighting in the template's directive blocks it would not be 100% correct.

There are a few editors that support TT style templating [here](http://www.template-toolkit.org/download/#editors), but if you want it in `Notepad++` you will probably have to write the .xml for it (which I imagine a few people will be vary grateful for).